# Moderation tools

Tags: bug, design, 10k-tools

The link to moderation tools seems to be missing for me. As Scott Morrison kindly explained in https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/20/12705, it is supposed to be here in the toolbar:

[image: toolbar without mod tools]

The [tools](https://mathoverflow.net/tools) as such work properly. In case it is relevant, I’m using Firefox 14.0.1 on Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No no, there is no link anymore.

You go to "review" and then you should see "tools" somewhere on the top part of the page (below the top menu, though).

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. Moderators have a 'mod' link there, and I was expecting that 10k users would have it too.

Comment: @Scott: One of the perks of being a mod. The rest of us has to go through an elaborate measure of clicks.

Comment: Well, clicking that 'mod' link takes me somewhere 'moderator only' anyway (reviewing posts flagged for moderator attention), so I guess it makes sense.

Comment: Oh. Thanks, I should have found that myself, I’m sorry for the misguided question.

Comment: @Emil: It's fine. It's a good excuse for creating more tags on meta.